# Hexadecimal data stored in SQL

Tags: t-sql, hex

[image: screen grab - hexadecimal data]

Please see screen grab. 
I am using a finance application and T-SQL. I would just like to understand why data would be stored on a db table in hexadecimal as opposed to integer, and why it would follow the format of 8-4-4-4-12 characters (total: 32). 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format) (or, in Microsoft parlance, a GUID) - normally used for ensuring `UNIQUE`ness in `PRIMARY KEY`s across different servers in a distributed system - if your system isn't distributed, there's no reason not to use simple autogenerated `INTEGER` as `PK`s.

Comment: Unless you need more keys than an `int` can provide. (`BigInt` anyone?) Or need to combine values from different sources without collisions, e.g. `select Id from LeftHandedUsers union all select Id from RightHandedUsers;`. Or you want to "future proof" against growth (or a merger) requiring multiple servers. Or ... .

Comment: @HABO - fair points - I did mention the `need to combine values from different sources without collisions`, but you're correct about the "future-proofing". Had to do such a merger once - not having unique PKs across servers was a pain!